# Flutter Firebase – Retrieve array & map data?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I want to retrieve data from Firestore and show them in my flutter app , but the document has a map called 'users' , my question is how I can access to This map field ?

[image: Firebase]

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Channels')
        .where('participants', arrayContains: UserInfoData.userID)
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
      switch (streamSnapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );

        default:
          if (streamSnapshot.hasError) {
            print(streamSnapshot.hasError.toString());
          } else {
            final channels = streamSnapshot.data!.docs;
            if (channels.isEmpty) {
              return Text('ff');
            } else
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: channels.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) => ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage:
                        NetworkImage(channels[i]['announceImage']),
                  ),
                  title: Text(channels[i]['reciverID']),
                ),
              );
          }
      }
      return Text('ok');
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: The same way that you access to another attributes: `channels[i]['announceImage']` so you can call `channels[i]['users']`, right? But you get a map instead a string.

Comment: yes I got a map how I can fetch the data like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the values over here just like any other map containing keys. In your case, **users** is a map containing keys *lastname, name, userid*. **channels[i]['users']** would get you the **users** map. To get the value for a particular key ,you can think of **channels[i]['users']** as a whole, like  an array.

So you could get the values by doing the following :

String lastname = channels[i]['users']['lastname']
String name = channels[i]['users']['name']